# Type annotation in Python

Tags: python, annotations, type-hinting

how to write the **:type** annotation in Python in case the argument can have different types?

```
    """
    :type param_name: type1|type2
    """
```

or

```
    """
    :type param_name: type1 / type2
    """
```

PyCharm accepts the 2nd variant

Comment: Is there a more general type that applies to both of them? Could you use one of the existing [ABCs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#module-collections.abc) to show the *interface* they must provide?

Comment: @jonrsharpe let's assume the function can apply both the boolean and the user model instance <User> and depend on this parameter it can choose what to do. I'm just interesting to know how to write doc-strings in python correctly. Should it be a "|" or "/" or some other type divider in case the parameter can be different type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the *Sphinx project notation*, which incidentally was rejected for inclusion in the [PEP 484 -- *Type Hints* proposal](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#other-backwards-compatible-conventions).

`:type` is an [info field list](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/domains.html#info-field-lists), and there isn't really all that much of a formal specification for these. The documentation example uses `or`:

```
:type priority: integer or None
```

but note that `integer` isn't a formal type, nor is `None` (it is a singleton object).

These are *documentation* constructs, not type hints, really. That PyCharm supports these at all is nice, but these are not a Python standard.

I'd stick with proper type annotations instead. That means using a [`Union` type](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#union-types):

```
Union[type1, type2]
```

You can put these in a `# type:` comment if you need to support Python 2.